# Is there any parameter that flags I want all classes to be serialized (or my entire application) without implementing serializable interface?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, serialization

Is there any parameter I can set at my Java Project where I can flag that all classes to be serialized, without having to implement the serializable interface? (My project is in Java Web using Java EE architecture running on Glassfish 4 server).

Comment: No. As you normally don't want this.

Comment: @lexicore need to serialize my entire application for clustering.